# Wrong url in SESSION variable when browser fails to load image url

Tags: php, session, url, redirect

I've got a front controller which stores the previous page url in a `$previousPageUrl` variable, and then stores the current page URL in a `$_SESSION['url']` variable:

```
session_start(); // starts the session

if (isset($_SESSION['url'])) {
    $previousPageUrl = $_SESSION['url'];
}

$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This way, I should be able to redirect to the previous page url whenever I want.

The problem is that this `$_SESSION['url']` variable uncannily changes at a certain moment, returning the url of a **.gif** image.

I noticed that this url was wrong. When I changed it in my template, this strange behaviour suddenly turned back to normality, and everything worked as it should.

Can someone please explain me what was going on? How can a wrong image url interfere with a session variable?

Comment: Can you not just use `history.back()` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: @putvande Is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` safe? Should I validate it somehow? (Anyway, my question regarded another argument) :)

Answer (score 0):

With the information given i can only assume...

I assume you are using a .htaccess with rewrite rules that rewrites everything to your frontcontroller?

If so:
In your html you have a image this creates a request, but if the url to the image is invalid the rewrite rules will rewrite it to your frontcontroller were the session variable is set.
Thus the invalid image url will be in the session.

Comment: I didn't ever edit my .htaccess, it's like when I installed php environment on my system. Could the default rewriting rules interfere with session variables?